# How to get the count of GROUP BY query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I get the count of a GROUP BY SQL query?

```
SELECT     Voter.*, temp100.YadiNo, temp100.CountHouseNo
FROM       temp100 
INNER JOIN Voter ON (temp100.HouseNo = Voter.HouseNo) AND (temp100.YadiNo = Voter.YadiNo)
WHERE      (((temp100.YadiNo) Between " & txtpartno.Text.Trim & " And " & txtpartno1.Text.Trim & ") 
AND        ((temp100.CountHouseNo) Between " & txtfamilymeb.Text.Trim & " And " & txtfamilymeb1.Text.Trim & "))
ORDER BY   voter.houseno
```

This means I has displayed group by house number.
I want the count of this group of house numbers.

Comment: Just the count of `House Number`? So, why do you need all the fields for Vote table? Could you show the structure of your Tables both for `Voter` and `temp100`?

Comment: thanks for reply but i want count of hose no means  the above query shows the output like eg. 11,11,2,2,4,4 here is three group of hose no i want three as output  is it poissible

Comment: could you provide a table or a picture for what output do you want? You could make even a simple table in your question above. Just edit it.

Comment: What are the three groups of House Number? Could you again show a simple table output of what you want?

Comment: it show the result which i want  but                             .eg.
it gives output like this


name  house no 
ABC         10
XYZ 10
PAR 10

LMN 20
PQR 20
JKL 20

STV 30
DEF 30

I want it gives there is 3 group  house no
Is it possible

Comment: Are ABC, XYZ, PAR, LMN House Numbers? Or is it the number itself, that is, 10 10 20 20 20 30 30? Or both?

Comment: here ABC,XYZ  are name of the person and 10,10,10,20,20 are the house no

Comment: What is the field name for voter's name? In your example it shows only the House Number.

Comment: <pre>voter.SrNo, voter.YadiNo, voter.fullname, voter.houseno, voter.address, voter.Gender, voter.Age, voter.CardNo , temp100.YadiNo temp100.CountHouseNo
FROM       temp100 
INNER JOIN Voter ON (temp100.HouseNo = Voter.HouseNo) AND (temp100.YadiNo = Voter.YadiNo)
WHERE      (((temp100.YadiNo) Between " & txtpartno.Text.Trim & " And " & txtpartno1.Text.Trim & ") 
AND        ((temp100.CountHouseNo) Between " & txtfamilymeb.Text.Trim & " And " & txtfamilymeb1.Text.Trim & "))
ORDER BY   voter.houseno</pre> this is my query name means full name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a guess, this would count number of voters per House No., like:

```
 SELECT     Voter.houseno, COUNT(*) as CountHouseNo
 FROM       temp100 
 INNER JOIN Voter ON (temp100.HouseNo = Voter.HouseNo) AND (temp100.YadiNo = Voter.YadiNo)
 WHERE      (((temp100.YadiNo) Between " & txtpartno.Text.Trim & " And " &   txtpartno1.Text.Trim & ") 
 AND        ((temp100.CountHouseNo) Between " & txtfamilymeb.Text.Trim & " And " &  txtfamilymeb1.Text.Trim & "))
 GROUP BY   Voter.houseno
 ORDER BY   Voter.houseno
```

And if you want to include the `YadiNo` (whatever does this mean), you could do like this:

```
 SELECT     Voter.houseno, temp100.YadiNo, COUNT(*) as CountHouseNo
 FROM       temp100 
 INNER JOIN Voter ON (temp100.HouseNo = Voter.HouseNo) AND (temp100.YadiNo = Voter.YadiNo)
 WHERE      (((temp100.YadiNo) Between " & txtpartno.Text.Trim & " And " &   txtpartno1.Text.Trim & ") 
 AND        ((temp100.CountHouseNo) Between " & txtfamilymeb.Text.Trim & " And " &  txtfamilymeb1.Text.Trim & "))
 GROUP BY   Voter.houseno, temp100.YadiNo
 ORDER BY   Voter.houseno
```

`COUNT()` is an aggregate function that normally is paired with `GROUP BY` clause.

See example [here](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Comment: thanks for reply  it show the result which i want  but                    .eg.
it gives output like this


name  house no 
ABC         10
XYZ 10
PAR 10

LMN 20
PQR 20
JKL 20

STV 30
DEF 30

I want it gives there is 3 group  house no
Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

```
U can't use group by with order by,
so change order by to group by 
like this

***SELECT     Voter.*, temp100.YadiNo, temp100.CountHouseNo
FROM       temp100 
INNER JOIN Voter ON (temp100.HouseNo = Voter.HouseNo) AND (temp100.YadiNo = Voter.YadiNo)
WHERE      (((temp100.YadiNo) Between " & txtpartno.Text.Trim & " And " & txtpartno1.Text.Trim & ") 
AND        ((temp100.CountHouseNo) Between " & txtfamilymeb.Text.Trim & " And " & txtfamilymeb1.Text.Trim & "))
GROUP BY   voter.houseno***
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  This query is work perfectly but i want                                  .eg.
it gives output like this


name  house no 
ABC         10
XYZ 10
PAR 10

LMN 20
PQR 20
JKL 20

STV 30
DEF 30

I want it gives there is 3 group  house no
Is it possible